# How to set encoding to PostgreSQL data base?

Tags: linux, postgresql, encoding

I cant see cyrillic symbols in PostgreSQL 9.1 on Linux Mint. So i want to create new bd with cyrillic encoding. I says:

```
CREATE DATABASE ekb_1 ENCODING 'CP1251' TEMPLATE postgistemplate;
```

but get error:

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE ekb_1 ENCODING 'WIN1251' TEMPLATE postgistemplate;
ERROR:  encoding WIN1251 does not match locale ru_RU.UTF-8
ПОДРОБНОСТИ:  The chosen LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding UTF8.
```

i try to add `lc_type 'ru_RU.WIN1251'` but not help.
Whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname ENCODING 'win1251'
   lc_ctype='ru_RU.CP1251'
   lc_collate='ru_RU.CP1251'
  TEMPLATE template0;
```

If the `ru_RU.CP1251` locale doesn't exist, create it with `sudo locale-gen ru_RU.CP1251` (Ubuntu-style, I assume Mint is similar in this regard) and **restart postgres** (it doesn't pick up new locales dynamically, and the error message is confusing).

The `postgistemplate` db would be accepted as a template only if it has the same encoding, which is unlikely given the context. Presumably it's in `UTF-8`.

In this case, there are two options in theory, not sure if any is practical:

1. create the database with `template0` as mentioned in the command above, and then play the postgis initialization script inside it.
2. recreate the `postgistemplate` database in `win1251` encoding assuming it's supported by postgis.

Personally, I'd try to solve the problems with UTF-8 that led you to try a different encoding in the first place, and stay with that encoding.